# How much of the world's website traffic is attacks?

Tags: traffic, statistics, botattack

Does anyone have any statistics on how much of the total of the world's website traffic is
malicious? Every day I am amazed by the number of requests for .dll and similar things which don't appear anywhere on my (static) website. What proportion of the world's web traffic is like this?

(It says that this "appears subjective and is likely to be closed" so I'm marking it community wiki.)

Comment: Hmm, is this question likely to lead to argument?

Comment: View it live on Akamai: http://www.akamai.com/html/technology/dataviz1.html

Answer (score 1):

Going through my server's access logs, its actually relatively low (for me), approximately 5-7%. The funny thing is, I'm using Linux but hide the server signature, so of the 5-7% of 'bad' requests, most of those are trying common Windows exploits.

Occasionally I see someone trying to play with form data, looking for accessible installations of phpmyadmin, trying ancient wordpress vulnerabilities, etc. However, by way of comparison, its rare.

Note, that's just HTTP traffic. Its very common for most connection attempts to mail / ssh / ftp servers to be bogus / brute force attempts.

It is possible to generate statistics here, but that's statistics per domain. You can't just 'average' all of those and come up with a number, that makes the bad assumption that all attacks are just random trial and error attempts to find something vulnerable.